# How to restart REST Services?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, restart

I want to restart the REST service since even after adding a new service or services I don't see any change in the help page at all and afterward all the services don't work... Is their any solution to this... worst case scenario I have to create a new project all over again...

By the way Im using C# .NET 4.0

Comment: You may want to post some code of the services that aren't working, along with the configuration of those services.  It doesn't have to be the full code, but enough so we can see how it's built and configured.

Comment: included the code for the service below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont actually host the service yet. I just run the service then use a client windows application and run it.

my config is just the basic config.. Actually when i create a new project and copy these codes it works again. So i think this might be an issue with Microsoft WCF REST itself

and sometimes when I add a new service may it be any of the crud functionality they also don't show in the help and have a not found exception.

Thank you :)